# Why WordPress uses `endwhile;` inside the templates?

Tags: php

We often see this insdie the WordPress templates:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
...
endwhile;
```

Do you have any idea why not using braces or "curly brackets" {} for `while` loop? What is the gain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220682/correct-use-of-curly-braces-vs-alternative-synax/

Comment: There are actually some advantages, but I don't like to answer my questions @czerspalace

Answer (score 1):

According to the wordpress handbook on [**php coding standards**](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/coding-standards/php/), braces should be used for all blocks in the style shown below:

```
if ( condition ) {
    action1();
    action2();
} elseif ( condition2 && condition3 ) {
    action3();
    action4();
} else {
    defaultaction();
}
```

> The use of braces means ***single-statement inline control structures***
>   are prohibited so it's better to use the [**alternative syntax for
>   control structures**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (e.g. `if`/`endif`, `while`/`endwhile`) in this scenario,
>   especially in template files where PHP code is embedded within HTML:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="hfeed">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID() ?>" class="<?php post_class() ?>">
                <!-- ... -->
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I am not stingy on points when my questions are in question, this was so close I really several times upvoted and then reset, eventually something prevail to the upvote, but I haven't seen what is the gain?

Comment: And please don't mix this with http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220682/correct-use-of-curly-braces-vs-alternative-synax/, after a check I saw your answer is almost identical with one answer from there.

Comment: I just quoted the documentation mostly, the key point being the prohibition of **single-statement inline control structures**

Comment: I see now sorry, so you don't see any gain? @TunjiAyoola

Answer (score 0):

It's just another way of writing it, mostly a stylistic choice. I use while loops with curly brackets, and find while : endwhile very hard to read.

Edit: previously asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220682/correct-use-of-curly-braces-vs-alternative-synax). tl;dr: same answer.